# Can I disable Win10 from changing default audio device to the most recently plugged in one?

Tags: windows-10, audio

Currently, Windows 10 changes the default audio device to whatever was most recently plugged in.

Is it possible to disable Windows from changing the default audio device when a new audio device is installed (ie. plugged in), if the previous default audio device is still present?

This applies to both playback and recording devices.

EDIT: I should clarify that it seems to set it to the most recently *installed* device, whereas it doesn't do it when an already installed device is plugged back in to the same usb port.

Comment: Try in *Settings > Devices > AutoPlay* to set to Off the option of "Use AutoPlay for all media and devices".

Comment: @harrymc I don't think that setting has anything to do with audio playback/recording devices, only with storage media, such as removable drives and memory cards

Comment: Did you try it and it didn't help?

Comment: @harrymc that is correct, I have tried it, and it made no difference to the behavior